# How to add framenumber in a plain frame

Tags: latex, beamer

I have some frames in my presentation, where I want to get rid of my standard Headline/Footline since i need the space for figures, which i include using `\includegraphics`. These figures take the whole space. Now i want to **inset the frame number at the bottom right corner**.

Note. I use the standard theme with a custom headline/footline. A working minimum example can be found here:
http://rapidshare.com/files/429008846/Beamer.zip

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgf}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%new color
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\def\textboxcolor{Gray}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\hspace{0.01\textwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.88\textwidth}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}
Organisation - Institution&%
&%
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{pictures/logos/logo_ohne_text.jpg}\\
\hline\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hspace{0.01\textwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.88\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.35\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}%
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\hline%
\raggedright\begin{minipage}{0.3cm}\includegraphics[width=0.30cm]{pictures/logos/quadrat.jpg}\end{minipage}\ \insertauthor &%
\centering \    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}& &%
Seite \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber\\
\hline\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{frame}{Normal Frame}
      \begin{block}{Blocktitle}
        Text
      \end{block}
    \end{frame}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{frame}[plain]{Frame with Images}
       \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{pictures/cf.png}
            \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{pictures/cf.png}\\
            \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{pictures/cf.png}
            \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{pictures/cf.png}
        \end{center}
        \begin{pgfpicture}{0}{0}{12.8cm}{9.6cm}
            \pgfputat{\pgfxy(10.62,1.05)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{ %
              \tiny{\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}}}
        \end{pgfpicture}
    \end{frame}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is the standard frame
http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2246/unbenanntzv.png

Comment: and this is the plain frame with images, where the frame number should be added at the bottom right corner http://img178.imageshack.us/img178/6476/unbenannt2tu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my original answer, I requested some pictures, which you posted. Many thanks; those were very helpful.

---

Your slide looks like it's using the Graz theme [1]. I downloaded that and came up with this solution. Try this (replace my \usetheme{Graz} with whatever you've called your version, as perhaps you've modified it a little):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf} % make sure you use this!
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Graz}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{images/uni_logo}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]{Test slide}
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0}{0}{12.8cm}{9.6cm} % see Note 1

    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(10.62,1.05)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{ % see Note 2
              \tiny{\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}}}

   \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.4,1.1)}{\pgfimage[width=0.95\textwidth]{figure}} % see Note 3

  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Note 1:** If you're unfamiliar with pgf[2], the syntax is:

```
\begin{pgfpicture}{start x}{start y}{end x}{end y}
```

So you could probably get away with just a pgf picture with {0}{0}{12.8}{1.05}, which would fill the whole width (0 -> 12.8cm x width) and just give you enough for the footer page number (0 -> 1.05cm y height).

However, if you leave it, you can use pgf to place your images as well. It's up to you. It doesn't affect anything to leave it the size of the whole frame.

**Note 2:** Alter these coordinates however you'd like. You can flip back and forth between a default slide and this one to tweak those coordinates until there is no discernible difference in the page #/tot pages listing between the two.

One note is that if you start adding text and what have you to the frame, there is a *slight* chance that the placement of the pgfbox might get knocked around. If it does this, just get your frame how you like it with the figures and redo the coordinates of \pfgputat to get it where you want.

**Note 3:** I took a screenshot of the figures from your link above and used pgf to place it in my frame. Your title is left aligned whereas mine is in the default centered position, but overall hopefully this looks like what you want (the LaTeX commands above generated this): [IMAGE](http://sites.google.com/site/jwhendytank/home/beamer_footline.png).

Like I said, just tweak the various coordinates to get everything where you want.

---

**Update 11/5:**

As I suggested in Note 2, adding things to the frame might mess up the placement. I have looked at your updated code and made pgf play nicely. It probably should be considered a "hack" since all it's doing is overcoming the downshift caused by the \includegraphics command. Essentially, it  looks like pgfbox can't reside where there are graphics placed with this method so you have to create a box "artificially" high up on the slide to force it to appear... but this works! I actually tweaked it so that if you go into full screen mode, there should be no shift whatsoever between "Seite 1/2" on the first slide and "2/2" on the second. Here it is:

```
\begin{pgfpicture}{0}{0}{12.8cm}{9.6cm}
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(10.585,9.74)}{\pgfbox[left,base]{ %
      \tiny{\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}}}
\end{pgfpicture}
```

Let me know how that goes!

---

[1] www . ist . tugraz . at/staff/weiglhofer/misc/tugbeamer/

[2] PGF manual on ctan: www . ctan . org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf in base/doc

Comment: I added some links to my questions, i hope it is more clear now, what i want. Basically, i want to add the frame number in that slide at the bottom right corner.
What i am looking for is a text box with the frame number that i can place in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Downloading that theme now (I'm familiar with it) so I can work with the same theme and will try to get you a solution shortly.

Comment: Re-read my solution -- I edited it to what I think will work for you.

Comment: Hendy, thanks for your help so far, I get your point now, i did not know the pgf package and i am surprised to see, that i can add textboxes with it. Since i can place a textbox where i want, this seems like a good solution for me. But I noticed, it does not work well together with the \includegraphics command. Basically i use the standard theme, but override the headline and footline with the graz theme. I added now a minimumexample of my code and uploaded a working example. In this example it is shown, that the pgfbox is shifted downwards by the figures, so that it is not shown.

Comment: I see that i can just use the pgf commands to add my figures, but i would like to keep the \includegraphics command, since i am familiar with it.

Comment: @Roland: See my added section, "Update 11/5" and the new \pgfpicture command lines. Replace your existing coordinates with this and it should work for you: \pgfxy(10.585,9.74). It's "cheating" but it works! While the "programmer" in me doesn't like to not understand the "proper" way... at the end of the day it seems that what matters is showing good looking slides that look how you want, whether or not they're hacked to be that way! Let me know if these do the trick.

Comment: Hendy, I agree, it's not very "nice" in a programmers point of view, but at the end of the day, it works and the slides look the way i want. Thats the reason, why i consider this problem as solved. 
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to temporarily use another layer to display the framenumbers, e.g. the navigation symbols. This has the additional advantage, that this layer is rendered on top of the frame content and thus will be visible even for full screen images.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}

%new color
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\def\textboxcolor{Gray}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\hspace{0.01\textwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.88\textwidth}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}
Organisation - Institution&%
&%
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}\\
\hline\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hspace{0.01\textwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.88\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.35\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}%
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}\hline%
\raggedright\begin{minipage}{0.3cm}\includegraphics[width=0.30cm]{example-image}\end{minipage}\ \insertauthor &%
\centering \    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}& &%
Seite \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber\\
\hline\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Normal Frame}
    \begin{block}{Blocktitle}
    Text
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
        \color{black}%
      \tiny%
      \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalpagenumber]%
      \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
    }
    \begin{frame}[plain]{Frame with Images}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}

        \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}
    \end{frame}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using a simple solution for that:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\footnotesize\insertframenumber{} / \insertmainframenumber}
```

It replaces the navigation symbols bar by your frames numbers. It appears in the right bottom corner of every frame (not only [plain] frames).